# What is analog of AddFieldTo on FastCube 2 components for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, migration

What is analog of `AddFieldTo` on `FastCube 2` components for Delphi? We've used the following code before:

```
TfcxSlice.AddFieldTo(FieldName, Caption, rf_CapXAx);
```

The problem is caused by the new `TfcxCommonFieldsOfRegion` class:

```
private
  procedure Delete(AIndex: TfcxSmallCount);
  function Add(AField: TfcxCommonFieldOfRegion): TfcxSmallCount;
  procedure Insert(AField: TfcxCommonFieldOfRegion; AIndex: TfcxSmallCount);
```

So, there is no strict way to change `TfcxCommonFieldsOfRegion` object.

Comment: you should ask this the vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new code:

```
XAxisContainer.AddDimension(TfcxSliceField, FieldName, Caption);
```